# No logro click sobre button

Tags: selenium-webdriver, click, chromedriver

tengo este HTML (inspección de código) de AFIP en el que necesito hacer click en Aceptar:

```
<input type="button" name="aceptar" value="Aceptar" onclick="javascript:go('../presentacion/presentacion.jsp?menuId=menu_presentacion');" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" title="Aceptar">
```

mi código es:

```
WebElement btnVep = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[contains(text(),'Presentaciones de declaraciones juradas y pagos po')]"));
btnVep.click();
```

**esta seria la línea que no funciona:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='button'][value='Aceptar']")).click();
```

parece muy simple la solución, pero no entiendo xq no me funciona.
graciass

---

mil disculpas si no fui lo suficientemente claro.
Lo que ocurre es que trato de automatizar la instrucción Click en un botón Aceptar para que acceda a una pagina determinada. Envio un print de pantalla:
[image: El que señalo es el button que se debe cliquear]

lo que tengo escrito en mi código es (la línea que parece no funcionar es la última):

@Test

public void abrirAfip() {
//1-Definir donde esta el chromedriver
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "..\ClaseITViernes\Drivers\chromedriver.exe");
//2-Definir que navegador voy a usar
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

```
                        //3-abrir el chrome en la pagina selenium.dev
                        driver.get("https://auth.afip.gob.ar/contribuyente_/login.xhtml");
                        
                        //maximiza el navegador
                        driver.manage().window().maximize();
                        
                        //borra las cookies
                        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
                        
                        
                        WebElement txtCuit = driver.findElement(By.id("F1:username"));
                        txtCuit.sendKeys("XXXX");
                        
                        //simular que se presiona enter
                        txtCuit.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
                        
                        WebElement txtPass = driver.findElement(By.id("F1:password"));
                        txtPass.sendKeys(clave);
                        
                        //simular que se presiona enter
                        txtPass.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
                        
                        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
                        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//p[contains(text(),'Presentaciones de declaraciones juradas y pagos po')]")));
                        
                        
                        WebElement btnVep = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[contains(text(),'Presentaciones de declaraciones juradas y pagos po')]"));
                        btnVep.click();
                        
                        //WebDriverWait espera = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
                        //espera.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("aceptar")));
                                
                        //WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
                        //wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.container div.row.justify-content-md-center div.col-md-9.col-xs-12 div.mt-4.card div.card-body div.text-right > input.btn.btn-sm.btn-primary:nth-child(4)")));
                        // /html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/div/div/div/div/input[2]
                        
                        WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
                        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='button'][value='Aceptar']")).click();
                        
                                                    
                        
            
            
}



}
```

Espero haber sido lo suficientemente claro con la duda.
Sds y graciasss

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Qué error aparece?